# Service ordering with a dependency on a conditional unit

Tags: systemd-unit

On startup, service `process_queue` starts if `ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=/unfinished_queue_jobs`, clears that directory, then stops.

Service `accept_new_jobs` should start after `process_queue` completes, or immediately if that dependency's condition fails.

*Ideally*, the unit file of `process_queue` doesn't have to reference `accept_new_jobs` in any way (`Before=` etc.)

What is the best way to express these dependencies with systemd?

Comment: Why can you not use directives such as `Before`, `After`, `Wants`, etc? That's the best way to achieve what you want. Can you provide what your systemd units contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failing conditions or asserts will not result in the unit being moved into the "failed" state. The conditions and asserts are checked at the time the queued start job is to be executed. The ordering dependencies are still respected, so other units are still pulled in and ordered as if this unit was successfully activated, and the conditions and asserts are executed the precise moment the unit would normally start and thus can validate system state after the units ordered before completed initialization.

> Note that [After= and Before=] are independent of and orthogonal to the requirement dependencies as configured by Requires=, Wants=, Requisite=, or BindsTo=. It is a common pattern to include a unit name in both the After= and Wants= options, in which case the unit listed will be started before the unit that is configured with these options.

Therefore I think I can just use After= and Wants= to achieve this. I'll test it.